# What if model doesn't match controller naming?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Say I have this setup:

My model is 'content', and I want to use this model in 2 controllers.

blog_controller.rb
article_controller.rb

My 'content' model has a property 'content_type' which tells me if this content is a 'blog' or a 'article'.

This seems to prevent me from doing:

resources :article
resources :blog

right?  since the models are different?  or can I still do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can still do it.

In your routes file, the `resources` method is, by default, looking for a controller of the same name that you pass it. So regardless of what the model's name is, if you have a controller named `blog_controller` you can do `resources :blog`

Comment: but won't this effect things like the form helper?

Comment: You would be passing :url => `articles_path` into the form helper so it knows to submit to there and trigger the create action in the articles_controller (assuming this is the form for 'new')

Answer (score 1):

In classic SO fashion, instead of answering your question I'm going to criticism your implementation ;-)

I think the root of your problem is that you want a single table for content, with code shared between articles and blogs. In rails, the way to do that is called "[Single Table Inheritance](http://code.alexreisner.com/articles/single-table-inheritance-in-rails.html)".